# See def __str__(self): in the code below. It does not influence on the output, but should. Expect assistance

Tags: python, string

import random

class Server:
    def **init**(self):
        """Creates a new server instance, with no active connections."""
        self.connections = {}

```
def add_connection(self, connection_id):
    """Adds a new connection to this server."""
    connection_load = random.random()*10+1
    # Add the connection to the dictionary with the calculated load
    if connection_id != None:
     self.connections[connection_id] = connection_load

def close_connection(self, connection_id):
    """Closes a connection on this server."""
    # Remove the connection from the dictionary
    if connection_id != None:
        del self.connections[connection_id]

def load(self):
    """Calculates the current load for all connections."""
    total = 0
    # Add up the load for each of the connections
    for user in self.connections:
        total += self.connections[user]
    return total

def __str__(self):
    """Returns a string with the current load of the server"""
    return "{:.2f}%".format(self.load())
```

server = Server()
server.add_connection("192.168.1.1")

print(server.load())

server.close_connection("192.168.1.1")
print(server.load())

Answer (score 0):

Because you are never trying to print the variable `server` your method is never called.

If you want your `__str__` to be invoked you need to be printing an instance of `Server`:

```
print(server)
```

not

```
print(server.load())
```